# Cannot call ajax function in php

Tags: php, ajax

I want to call ajax from php(i put the function and the php at the same page) but i get error undefined index hash. please help me guys. this is my code:

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" integrity="sha256- 
FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8="
crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>
 <body>

 </body>
 </html>
 <?php
    echo $_POST["hash"];
 ?>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var hash = window.location.hash;
    $.ajax({
            url:"test.php",
            method:"POST",
            data:{hash:hash},
            success: function (data)
            {
            }
        });
</script>
```

Comment: "I want to call ajax from php"  You need to do some learning on the difference between client-side and server-side programming.  AJAX is a client-side technology.  PHP is server-side.  You can use AJAX to _make a request_ to a PHP page, but PHP cannot _call_ AJAX.  That's just not how it works.

Comment: so what should i do so i can call var hash in php using ajax?

Comment: Hard to say, as it is unclear what you are actually trying to do

Comment: Are you trying to make an AJAX request to the current page?

Comment: i want to get hash value dynamically in url. for example, localhost/test.php#1. i want to get 1, and send it to php.

Comment: yes, i make ajax request in test.php

Comment: Your error is coming from that fact that you are not checking if `$_POST['hash']` is set before echoing it. You're basically getting an `IndexOutOfRangeException`, but in PHP. Try `if isset($_POST['hash']) echo $_POST['hash']`, or `echo $_POST['hash'] ?? ""`.

Comment: already do that mr. matthew, but still no output when i echoing it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to have 2 files, say index.html:

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" integrity="sha256- 
FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8="
crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>
 <body>

 </body>
 </html>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var hash = window.location.hash;
    $.ajax({
            url:"test.php",
            method:"POST",
            data:{hash:hash},
            success: function (data)
            {
            }
        });
</script>
```

and test.php:

```
<?php
    echo $_POST["hash"];
 ?>
```

Comment: Where does it come from?

Comment: var hash = window.location.hash;

Comment: actually i want to get hash value from url dynamically, for example localhost/test.php#id=2, i want to get “2”,  so i make var hash = window.location.hash and sent it to php using ajax

Comment: @Harvey Please accept the answer if that is what you needed

Comment: still undefined index :(

Comment: Are you sure that your URL has a hash part? you can replace the part with data:{hash:"test"} to test if it works

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example `test.php`

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" integrity="sha256- 
FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8="
crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>
<body>

<script type="text/javascript">
var hash = window.location.href;
$.ajax({
        url:"test1.php",
        method:"POST",
        data:{hash:hash},
        success: function (data)
        {
             alert(data);
        }
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is the `test1.php`

```
<?php    echo $_POST["hash"];  ?>
```

Comment: still undefined index :(

Comment: Have you checked whether the ajax request is working ( using browser development tools)?. Ajax url should be complete path like "http://localhost/test1.php"